# i cant call my multidimensional array function from my main function. what is wrong with my parameters? declarations? variables? etc

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, func

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

#define MAX_VAL 100

//Function declaration
int input_values(int Z[][k], int j, int k);


int main(void)
{
 int A(int [ ][k], int, int);
 int m, n;
 char comm[100];

 while(1){
  printf("\n>>");
  gets(comm);


   if(strcmp(comm,"MAKE A")== 0)
    input_values(A, j, k  );
  }  



}
//make or overwrite matrix
int input_values(int Z[][k], int j, int k)
{
 int row, col;

 //DETERMINING THE SIZE OF MATRIX
  do{
   printf("Enter the number of rows: ");
   scanf("%d", &row);
    if(row>100)
     printf("Size is out of bounds! Size must be less than or equal to 100\n");
  }while(row>100);        
  do{
   printf("Enter the number of columns: ");
   scanf("%d", &col);
    if(col>100)
     printf("Size is out of bounds! Size must be less than or equal to 100\n");
  }while(col>100); 

 //ENTERING THE VALUES OF MATRIX
  for(j=0; j<row; j++)                                                                          
   for(k=0; k<col; k++){
    printf("A[%d][%d] = ", j, k);
    scanf("%d", &Z[j][k]);
    }

return Z[][];
}
```

Comment: We'll help you if you demonstrate that you've tried to help yourself. So go and do that, then come back and reword your question if you dont' have success.

Comment: What is your question? What problems are you having? What errors are you getting? You need to provide a lot more information.

Comment: @thelost, no, it's not C#, but we have the power to retag. :)

Comment: The return type of your function does not match int.

return Z[]][]  is not int! And you don't even use the return value.

You are using the array in your input_values function - you can use it to return directly.

Comment: im just a beginner. help me :(

Comment: @Kirk Woll is it worth it ? please read again the question. Not to mention the meaningless variable names.

Comment: @thelost, I agree it's probably not worth it in terms of answering his question.  But I don't like things in the wrong place. :)  **And whoever keeps changing this back to c#, STOP!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, `int Z[][k]` isn't valid syntax in C. Not as a declaration  and not as a parameter. And it certainly isn't C#.

Furthermore, `int A(int [ ][k], int, int);` is a forward declaration for a function. It is not a match for the 1st parameter of input_values.

I'm guessing you ended up with this notation for `A` because it gives no syntax errors. That is because the C compiler just ignores the invalid `k` in there.

Comment: That's a good point.  But whatever the case, it's emphatically not C#.

Comment: thank you very much:) anyway, could you help me on how to pass 2d arrays to functions? thanks:)